Unable to export FeatureCollection to cloud storage Server Erred
I try to export featurecollection to cloud storage, but I received server error 500 status. Anyone know how to resolve this?

my code is as follow:
var geojson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              110.55879758072791,
              1.2450856224188982
            ],
            [
              109.99917948330102,
              0.9744506682859395
            ],
            [
              110.24556017665782,
              0.7269981255807636
            ],
            [
              110.55953113895208,
              0.7232438001609154
            ],
            [
              110.68464221621196,
              0.9208288363406183
            ],
            [
              110.75184264397387,
              0.9766985669251795
            ],
            [
              110.55879758072791,
              1.2450856224188982
            ]
          ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
      }
    }
  ]
}
var y = ee.FeatureCollection(geojson)

Export.table.toCloudStorage(y, "testing-export-geojson-y", 'fa-rs-bucket', 'ee-carbon/development/testing-geojson-y', 'GeoJSON')

